# Issue with creating a table that successfully created in a different tablespace

Tags: oracle12c

I attempted the following, but I am receiving an `ORA-01950` error

```
ALTER USER USER1 QUOTA 200M ON NUSERS;
User altered.

GRANT SELECT ON HR.EMPLOYEES TO USER1;
Grant succeeded.

CONN USER1/USER;
Connected.

CREATE TABLE T3 AS SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES NUSERS;
CREATE TABLE T3 AS SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEES NUSERS
                                *

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Answer (score 0):

You said this: ALTER USER USER1 QUOTA 200M ON **NUSERS**;

Oracle responded: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace '**USERS**'

See the big bold **N** difference?